# WebRequest POST long value?

Tags: c#

I have a string with 300 rows, there is a way to do it POST?
Here is my code, is currently working on a limited amount of short letters:

```
WebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "http://thisisurl/test.php?ad=test&f=" + information_data);
req.Method = "POST";
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: You're not using the f parameter to post data are you?

Comment: f parameter its for post data

Comment: @user3915278 it is not *POSTing*. *POSTing* means, you write the data to the body of the Http message. (BTW: url has a length limitation. this is why you can't *"post"* a long data)

Comment: Ideal solution would be posting data as byte array. check this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx http://technet.rapaport.com/info/lotupload/samplecode/full_example.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to explain your problem right now and go ahead and give you a possible solution at the end.

You are hitting the character limit for url length / query parameter length. IE limits it as low as 2,083.

The data you are providing should be sent in the body of the http request, not the URL parameters.

A Post Request Normally is done in the following format(Code from the link).

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["username"] = "myUser";
    data["password"] = "myPassword";

    var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
}
```

This thread should have enough info if you want to use the WebRequest class instead:
[HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)